# Kendo dropdownliast select element containing a substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo DropDownList what I have to select an element by the text containing 8. I can select element by the full string, I only need to select it by a substring.

The partly working code looks like:

```
var ddlist = $("#HibaTipusKod_" + munkatargyaId).data("kendoDropDownList");
console.log(ddlist);
ddlist.value("8/a");
ddlist.trigger("change");
```

My need is:

```
ddlist.value(*startswith/contains*"8");
ddlist.trigger("change");
```

At the logging I can see it right.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes I've tried:
    ':contains("8")'

Comment: What in case of finding more than one? Gets the first ?

Comment: Yes, I need the first if there are more. Usually there's one or two of this kind.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
var options = ddlist.dataSource.options.data;                 
$.each(options, function(i, item) {
    if (item.text.indexOf('8') !== -1) {
      dropdownlist.select(i);
      return false;
    }
});
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UbubEtOj/4)

Bare in mind that using indexOf to search for the sub-string will be case sensitive, there are lots of alternative methods that could better suit your needs in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript).

Comment: I get an error like:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Function.each

I've tried this before, but got the same error.

Comment: Sounds like it's having trouble getting the dataSource. Your ddlist variable should be defined like this:  `var ddlist = $("#CSS-ID-HERE").data("kendoDropDownList");`

Comment: Updated the anwser with a bigger part of my code. If I'm not mistaken, it's the same.

Comment: Try printing the dataSource to the console and check how it's structured or check my demo, there's a link to it my answer. I hope this helps.